# Where to centralize all fetch() requests in React? And accessing context

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have a react app where I have centralized all my API call in a .js file as follow:

```
export async function api_call_1(a, b) {
    //builds and sends a fetch request
    return someValue;
}

export async function api_call_2(c, d) {
    //builds and sends a fetch request
    return someOtherValue;
}

export async function api_call_3(e, f) {
    //builds and sends a fetch request
    return anotherValue;
}
```

Within my React components I do call these functions like

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const data = await api_call_1(a, b);
    this.setState({data: data})
}
```

Now the thing is that I want to use some data stored in a specific context (in particular the auth token sent in the header call).

Is there a way to access a context in these global API calls or should I just pass it on all my calls?

In general, looking for best practices to handle all this calls to my internal API.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

API class in src/API.js

```
class API {
    async getProjects() {
        var result = 
            fetch("http://your-hosting.com/api/projects")
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((a) => a);
        return result;
    }
}
export default API;
```

Projects class in src/Projects.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import API from './API.js'

class Projects extends Component {
    state = { 
        projects: []
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        new API().getProjects().then(result=> {
            this.setState({ projects: result });
        });
    }

    //render function here
}
export default Projects;
```